# how to implement a one-to-many LSTM network with output of different dimension at each time step

Tags: conv-neural-network, hyperparameter

I'm trying to replicate the controller described in "NEURAL ARCHITECTURE SEARCH WITH
REINFORCEMENT LEARNING"([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01578.pdf)) to find the best set of hyperparameters for a CNN.

The controller is a LSTM network, for which the output at each step are the probabilities to sample each value for a given hyperparameter.

for instance my search space could be:

space = {number of filters = [16,32,64,128],
         filter size = [3,5]}

Given this search space the RNN should output at step 1 a vector like [0.2,0.5,0.2,0.1] and a vector like [0.3,0.7] at step 2.

How to make the LSTM have different outputs dimensions at each step using tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Generally what is done in these sorts of situations, when you want to generate different outputs of different "types" is that you generate all output types every timestep and just take the appropriate values, ignoring the rest.

So to make this concrete, in your example you would have an RNN which outputs a 6-D vector, from which you take either the first 4 to predict the filters or the last 2 to take the filter size.